# Why do we need FROM in dockerfile for a java app?

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I have a very basic question about FROM line in dockerfile for a java application, like a spring boot app.

So we write it like:

```
FROM openjdk:11
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

In line 3 we are basically telling docker to use the application jar inside target folder for running the app inside container. Now when a jar is build for a java application, build process takes into account all the needed dependencies like those from jdk or those defined in POM etc.

So then why do we need FROM line? We already have all in our jar, isn't?

Comment: You need Java and the JDK itself.

Comment: .... and some libraries to run the jvm...

Comment: JVM is not part of your dependency list, even if it would, then who would interpret that jar in the end?

Comment: ah ok got it. I was under impression that a container already has a jvm..

Answer (score 1):

The FROM argument describes a base image to use.  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from

An analogy in a non containerized world would be sitting down to a computer freshly installed with some OS and various dependencies already setup for you.  Handy!

In this specific case, you are getting an image from OpenJDK.  https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk.

Edit to add detail: As a number of comments state, Java needs the JVM installed on some OS to run a Java program.  If you look down at image variants in the docker hub link, you'll see that you are requesting an image with Debian Linux and OpenJDK 11.

Comment: As an aside, is your build process containerized also?  Without knowing the details, there might be room for some harmonization between build and distribution.